# Quais são os cuidados a serem tomados ao utilizar top-level await em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

A [proposta para o *top-level* `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) acaba de ser finalizada, o que significa que esse recurso em breve fará parte da linguagem.

Até onde sei, esse recurso só estará disponível quando executado no contexto de módulos (assim como as declarações `import` e `export`).

Como o `await` é um recurso sobre-usado por muitos desenvolvedores, gostaria de saber quais são, pontualmente, os cuidados a serem tomados ao utilizar o *top-level* `await`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O *top-level* `await` (TLA) é um novo recurso do JavaScript que permite a utilização do operador `await` no escopo mais superior de módulos ECMAScript (ESM). Esse escopo mais superior chama-se *top-level*.

O comportamento do [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) no *module top-level* é o mesmo de quando é utilizado em funções assíncronas. Em resumo:

- No caso da promessa ser resolvida, o `await` retorna o valor da resolução.
- No caso da promessa ser rejeitada, o `await` lança o valor da rejeição.

### O que justifica o *top-level* `await`?

Em alguns casos, pode ser necessário carregar algum recurso assincronamente durante a inicialização de um módulo. Para que isso seja feito de forma própria, os `export`s do módulo, no mundo ideal, não devem ser efetivados até que todo o trabalho assíncrono de inicialização tenha sido concluído.

É isso que, basicamente, o *top-level* `await` resolve. Quando utilizado no *module top-level*, barrará a execução do resto do módulo (inclusive os `export`s do módulo) até que a promessa tenha sido resolvida.

Isso garante que o módulo só exportará seu conteúdo quando todas as promessas aguardadas em *top-level* tenham sido resolvidas ou uma qualquer delas tenha sido rejeitada. Esse comportamento de "curto-circuito" é similar ao [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

É claro que esse recurso **não deve ser sobre-utilizado** (veremos a seguir alguns pontos negativos de se fazer essa inicialização de recursos assincronamente). Mas, quando necessário, decerto pode ser bastante útil. O repositório da proposta (ainda em estágio três) menciona [alguns casos de uso](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await#use-cases) em que o *top-level* `await` pode fazer sentido.

### Quais são os cuidados a serem tomados ao utilizar o *top-level* `await`?

#### 1. O *top-level* `await` trava um módulo e seus descendentes

Esse talvez seja o pior dos problemas *facilitados* pelo *top-level* `await`. Devo ressaltar que o problema não se deve ao TLA em si, mas pelo fato de se fazer carregamento assíncrono de recursos no *top-level* de módulos.

Não tem como fugir disto – se um módulo **A** faz inicialização assíncrona, ele travará até a conclusão das promessas aguardadas. E, por conta desse bloqueio, todos os outros módulos que importam **A** (utilizando a sintaxe `import ... from 'A'`) também serão travados.

Esse travamento por descendência pode ser extremamente prolongado em longas cadeias de importação. Em alguns casos, utilizar [*dynamic imports*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) pode evitar esse problema se o módulo puder ser carregado de modo *lazy*.

Supondo que `a.mjs` contenha algum tipo de inicialização assíncrona, este módulo, que depende de A, também será bloqueado:

```
// Só será executado quando `A` terminar a inicialização...
import * as A from './a.mjs';

console.log(A);
```

Mas se a importação for feita utilizando *dynamic import*, que é assíncrono, este módulo não será bloqueado. Note que, neste caso, a importação deve ser feita dentro de uma função assíncrona. Se o `await` fosse feito em *top-level*, o comportamento seria o mesmo do exemplo anterior.

```
// Note agora que o carregamento do módulo `A` é lazy.
// Desse modo, este módulo não será bloqueado em detrimento de `A`.
//
// O módulo `A` será carregado somente quando a função `doStuff` for invocada.
export async function doStuff() {
  const A = await import('./a.mjs');
  console.log(A);
}
```

Comment: Ainda não acabei, mas o tempo tá meio corrido. Daqui a um tempo completo a resposta. Apesar disso, o que já está aí é o que julgo ser o mais importante.